# Time frame for running qhpvt

Tags: r

I am running a `qhpvt` function in R, with a data frame that has 613,500 rows, and about 30 columns. The functions looks like

```
 qhpvt(TestTblHyprlnksFrmtd16_0_613499SmallSize,"LCA Link","SubmitDate","n()")
```

And it is taking forever, already 2 hours plus and is still going. How long can I expect it to take?

Sample data from the table is as follows (the sample I am providing has only those column that are used in the query as well) :

```
LCA Link                                                                  SubmitDate
/h1bvisa-I-200-16270-175992/consultant-us-practitioner-infosys-limited    9/26/2016
/h1bvisa-I-200-16111-357816/lead-technical-support-engineer-ixia          4/28/2016
/h1bvisa-I-200-16270-176117/programmer-analyst-global-it-inc              9/26/2016
/h1bvisa-I-200-16270-390781/project-manager-syntel-inc                    9/26/2016
/h1bvisa-I-200-16270-290298/product-test-engineer-mellanox-technologies   9/26/2016
```

Comment: try it on subsets of your data and see how it scales with number of rows (and columns)?

Comment: yes true, that is what i am trying now. A beginner, have to learn. Anyhow the update for those like myself is that after 7 hours of running the trial, i had to forcefully stop the process as it almost halted my entire system, and i was not able to even switch to other apps/ simple stuff like chrome i was using.